# PRIMETIME | Issue linking hierarchal netlist

Tags: vlsi, asic, physical-design

I need help with a basic PT setup with hierarchal netlist.

Context:

- I have a design named top.v as described in diagram below:-
- TOP has two modules (CELL_A and CELL_B)
- CELL_A has one flop=FLOP1
- CELL-B has one flop=FLOP2

[image: TOP LEVEL DESIGN DESCRIPTION]

Commands I am running :

- read_verilog top.v
- set link_path “flop1.corner.db flop2.corner.db”
- link_design top

With above I am getting any useful error, but my design in not linked properly. Please refer the log snippet below:

[image: PT LOG SNIPPET]

Please advice if I am doing anything fundamentally wrong here.